# Win Forms (Accordion) Multi-level Drop-down Control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, accordion, infragistics

I am looking for a C# Win Forms(.NET 3.5) multi-level(or categorised) accordion menu control.

The menu on the right in the following URL is a demonstration of the behaviour that I would like to implement:
http://jsbin.com/oteze/edit#javascript,html (see HTML Combo but would like to support multiple levels)

For example, I would like to be able to navigate the following menu and select just a single item.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks,
f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps the [WinExplorerBar](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winexplorerbar.aspx#Overview) suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The [MainMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984267%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (the normal windows naitive menu) suits this purpose.